# How to create a filesystem with /etc/fstab entry on RHEL

Tags: linux, filesystems

For which command can create a filesystem and append it into `/etc/fstab` automatically?

Just like the AIX command `crfs -v jfs2 -d LV01 -m /backup -A yes` . The option `-A` means it will mount on next boot automatically, and I even don't need to  modify `/etc/filesystems` (as `/etc/fstab` on Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't such commands, but this can be easily scripted.